# Deny resource without ROLE in spring

Tags: spring

I am not able to deny (403) the resources that are without rules
When I try to access the resource / app1 / b it is not being denied
I'm not wondering where the problem is

CLASS WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter awsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signin", "/signup")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(awsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

CLASS AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class AwsCognitoJwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication;
        try {
            authentication = getAuthentication(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        } catch (ForbiddenException e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            handleUnauthorizedResponse(response, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, e);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            handleUnauthorizedResponse(response, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, e);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

CLASS AppResource

**The resource "*/app1/b*" is not being denied**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app1")
public class AppResource {

    @GetMapping
    @RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public Map all() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("nome", "Mauricio");
    }

    @GetMapping("/a")
    @RolesAllowed("XXS")
    public Map all2() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("nome", "XXX");
    }

    @GetMapping("/b")
    public Map noAuth() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("nome", "no auth");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like expected behavior.

```
.anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
```

These two lines allow access to any of your endpoints, as long as the user is *authenticated*.

What other behavior would you like?